# YUN. How to reset the micro controller from linux?

Tags: arduino-yun

As the title, I'd like to reset the Arduino sketch from the linux machine. Is it possible? how?

One solution could be to save the hex file inside the sd card and then upload it via the lua sketch but I think there is a smarter solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use command `reset-mcu`: it's a linux script that resets the 32u4 via GPIO

Answer (score 2):

According to the Yun schematic, GPIO18 of the SoC is connected to the MCU reset circuitry. Toggling it should allow you to reset the MCU.

Comment: I lightly understand what are you saying. Any ideas on how practically do it?

Comment: Depends on where you are when you want to reset it. C? Python? Shell?

Comment: python or shell.. c is only the last resource (I'm not good at C)

Comment: http://linino.org/doku.php?id=wiki:gpio